# Unable to install /delete/upgrade software due to linux-modules-5.15.0-50-generic package

Tags: upgrade

I am unable to install or delete some installed software applications and or commence automatic update of my Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS due to the above package.  I have followed above suggestions and still continue to get the same error. Help/advise, very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Please help us help you by showing error messages. Edit the question above by adding the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Yes, please copy and paste the error into your question. Also, it helps to format the error for your question as well by placing ``` on the line above the pasted error and ``` on the line after the pasted error. Thanks.

Comment: How to attach a screen shot here. There seems to be 1000 character limit. I am new to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with a an unwanted non-working kernel ( I presume that's what you mean and that your current kernel is newer ), try

> uname -a

Now you should be looking at a higher than 5.15.0-50 version.

Then:

> sudo apt remove linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
> linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic --verbose-versions

This should remove the old kernel that prohibits you from going forward.

Otherwise, follow the advice in the comments above and the community will take it from there.

Comment: How can I add a screenshot file here. I am new to this platform.

Comment: How can I add a *.png file here, so that you can check out error listing.

Comment: Can somebody help me on this issue please ???

Comment: @AndyM just copy and paste the output text, you don't need to add a screenshot. The community can't help you without proper indications as to where the problem lies. Have you tried implementing my answer above ?

Comment: --Cannot copy/paste, as there is 2000 character limit. Tried your reco, no success.

Comment: @AndyM you are a novice Ubuntu user. Best solution for you would be to backup your data and do a fresh 22.04. All your problems will be solved.

Comment: I agree I am novice, but the same error has been reported by 2-3 people here, and there seems no solution available.

Comment: @AndyM then go ahead and apply that solution

Comment: Which solution are you talking about. Nobody seems to have a solution, so far.